# ichol instead of chol in MATLAB 2013

Tags: matlab

I have a code that I used to run without any problem in MATLAB 2012.
But when I switched to MATLAB 2013 my code doesn't work anymore and I get the following error:

> CHOLINC has been removed.  Use ICHOL instead.

I'm using this line of code which is in cvx package and specifically in quad_form.m file:

> [ R, p ] = chol( Q );

And so I'm wondering how can I replace `chol` by `ichol`.

Comment: Are you sure that's where the error is? Because `chol` wasn't removed, `cholinc` was :/ are you maybe hiding matlab's `chol` function with a toolbox or user defined version that uses `cholinc` internally?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should read the documentation, it can be found by typing `help ichol` or `doc ichol`. Here is a copy as well: http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/ichol.html

I am not 100% sure, but my first try would be to check whether changing `chol` to `ichol` will do the trick.

---

If the problem is that the function call is made in code that you cannot alter, then (after you figure out what the call should be) you can create your own `chol` function that calls `ichol`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Dan suggested, matlab's `chol` is probably being "overridden" by a user- or toolbox-defined `chol` which internally calls `cholinc` (now `ichol`).

But more importantly, you should understand what is going on in your problem.   Cholesky facotrizations (`chol`) only work if your matrix `Q` is Hermitian and positive-semidefinite.

Probably, somebody wrote their own `chol` which attempts a Cholesky factorization, and if it fails, does an incomplete Cholesky factorization (`ichol`  / `cholinc`) instead.

You could just implement that yourself, e.g. assuming the matrix `Q` is real-valued:

```
%untested.
R = [];
p = [];

if Q==Q'  && all(eig(Q) >= 0)
   [R,p] = chol(Q);
else
   [R,p] = ichol(Q);
end
```

---

**addition**

You may want to use `try` & `catch`  instead of `if` & `else`, if you want to be completely sure that no hidden warnings/error messages cause your program to bail.

---

**edit**

Changed condition on `Q` to actually checking for positive semi-definiteness.  Thanks for pointing that out @woodchips.

Comment: Shiver. Using det(Q) > 0 to do that test is a bad idea in general.

Comment: @woodchips  hence the `try` & `catch`  alternative suggestion.

Comment: fixed.  Thanks for reminding me, @woodchips.  I'm a little rusty, evidently :/